# Using array in powershell function

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I have function in powershell with prarametres: vmname, hypervname, cred:

```
function backup-VM ([string]$vmname, [string]$hypervname,$cred)
{
......
}
```

I want to use this function in loop, using values from array, like this:

```
$arrayVM = Get-VM | select Name / get lists of Vitrual Machines
$arrayVMHost = Get-VMHost | select Name / get list of Vitrual Machines Host

for ($i=0; $i -lt $arrayVM.length; $i++) {
    backup-vm $arrayVM[$i] $arrayVMHost[0] $credentials
}

$arrayVM.Clear()
$arrayVMHost.Clear()
```

But this, doesn't work. What is wrong? How to pass values from array to function call?

Comment: You have only one VM on each hypervisor? That seems a little excessive

Comment: No, there are some VMs

Comment: Then why do you expect index `$i` in the `$arrayVM` array to correspond to index `$i` in the `$arrayVMHost` array? :-)

Comment: I want to execute function for more VMs.

fore example:
backup-vm "TEST-VM" "SERVER-HV" $credentials

in scripts should be $arrayVMHost[0] - always are one hyper-v host

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function backup-VM
{
   param([string]$vmname, 
         [string]$hypervname,
         $cred)

         Write-Host "Must DO something for $vmname on $hypervname"
}

$arrayVM =@("a","b","c")
$arrayVMHost=@("a-host","b-host","c-host")

for ($i=0; $i -lt $arrayVM.length; $i++) {
    backup-vm $arrayVM[$i] $arrayVMHost[$i] $credentials
}
```

So Id say that for you either $arrayVM or $arrayVMHost is not an array, either null or only 1 item.

Comment: But I want to get list of VMs from this command: $arrayVM = Get-VM | select Name. Your exaple using static names of VM

Comment: You need to check that get-vm returns an array then $arrayVM.GetType() or $arrayVM -is [array]

Comment: Its a System.Array. So i should convert this type to string which are using in function as parameters?

Comment: It returns an Array of objects, the value you want is in Name so you need to do $arrayVM[$i].Name or use a foreach like I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to accomplish with Get-VMHost and then using only the first one...but assuming thats really what you want, you could just use foreach instead of a for loop.

```
#get lists of Vitrual Machines    
$arrayVM = Get-VM | select Name  

# get list of Vitrual Machines Host
$arrayVMHost = Get-VMHost | select Name 

function backup-VM ([string]$vmname, [string]$hypervname,$cred) {
    Write-Host "Backup $vmname on $hypervmname with $cred"
}

foreach ($vm in $arrayVM) {
    Backup-VM $vm.Name $arrayVMHost[0].Name $credentials
}
```

This should work.

> But this, doesn't work. What is wrong? How to pass values from array
>   to function call?

Providing the actual error or what "doesn't work" will get you better answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Surround the `Get-VM ...` with @(...) to convert the returned value into an array